# ViewController - main view elements at (0,0) are obscured by navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a simple case where I am pushing a new viewcontroller onto a navigation controller stack.  This VC uses a xib and has a `UISearchBar` that is constrained to the top and left 'container' which in this case is simply the main View.

When I push this VC on the stack the search bar is not seen.  This is because the nav bar rests on top taking up the first 50 or so y points of the device screen.  (starting after the status bar presumably).

If I set the top container auto-layout constraint to 50, or some y-offset sufficient to counteract the height of the nav bar, I will see the search bar.

I am working on a project where I am pushing VC's onto a nav stack of a `UINavigationController` I did not create.  I am wondering what reasons could lead to this (what i would call buggy) behavior.  My understanding was that any viewController in a navController would have it's main view's frame adjust in the presence of nav/status/tab bars.  What can I do to ensure that origin (0,0) starts at screen origin + status bar height + nav bar height?  Furthermore, I would also like my VC's mainView's lower bound to end at the top of the tab bar also present on screen.  I have looked into various UIView and ViewController properties and have not found a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use xib file for designing your view controller, you should add this code to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
```

This line will make your view controller's view is laid out under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, any new `UIViewControllers` are done on storyboards and some developers hook up segues between the first and second `UIViewController`. The reason for this is because by implementing a pushing segue, the second`UIViewController` over the first one, the second one will inherit whatever properties the first one had (such as navigation bars, toolbar, tabbar) and it shows on the storyboard immediately.

So then it will be easier to work on the second `UIViewController` knowing how much space to allocate to `UINavigation` or `UITabbar`.

If your VC is done on an `XIB` interface instead of being hooked to the `UINavigationController` controlled stack of previous ViewControllers, then I am guessing you are not seeing the space that `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` supposedly takes up on your interface?

Perhaps you could try setting the constraints to begin at 64 points below the Top Layout Guide (to make space for `UINavigationBar`) and 49 above the Bottom Layout Guide (to make space `UITabbar`).